# Stiff muscle recovery after running

Tags: running, recovery, legs

After running, sometimes my legs muscles are stiff.

What's a way to speed up "recovery" when this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Rest and recovery is an essential part of any workout routine. Your after exercise recovery routine has a big impact on your fitness gains and sports performance and allows you to train much more effectively.
Some ways to go about this are:

1. Stretch: After a tough workout, consider gentle stretching. This is a simple and fast way to help your muscles recover.
2. Replace Fluids: You lose a lot of fluid during exercise and ideally, you should be replacing it during exercise, but filling up after exercise is an easy way to boost your recovery.
3. Eat Properly: After depleting your energy stores with exercise, you need to refuel if you expect your body to recover, repair tissues, get stronger and be ready for the next challenge.
4. Rest: Time is one of the best ways to recover (or heal) from just about any illness or injury and this also works after a hard workout.
5. Avoid Overtraining: One simple way to recovery faster is by designing a smart workout routine in the first place.

There are others such as getting ice baths and massage therapy, but do what is most suitable for your context. You can read/find more [here](http://www.mensfitness.com/training/endurance/4-tips-to-speed-up-muscle-recovery) and [here](http://sportsmedicine.about.com/od/sampleworkouts/a/After-Exercise.htm)

Happy recoveries!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand slightly on the very good answer from @lonecrusader1989, sports massages can get expensive, if you are looking for a similar, cheaper alternative then try a [foam roller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam_rolling). They are cheap to buy and will have a similar effect to sports massage and simple routines like [these](http://www.menshealth.co.uk/fitness/sports-injuries/4-foam-roller-exercises) can be done in your own home.